# Baking diffuse image with view transform applied results in an image with muted colors

Tags: texture-baking, baking

Using a simple test scene with a cube and a plane, both using a white diffuse BSDF and a simple area light, I'm trying to bake the diffuse component of this scene in a texture

For my specific use-case, it's important that the color accuracy of the baked image matches what I'm seeing when rendering in viewport / render mode.

When saving the baked image, I'm setting "Save as render" to apply the Filmic view transform, but the resulting .png image ends up having muted colors compared to the colors I'm seeing in viewport

[image: Baked image has muted colors compared to viewport render]

The image at the left side in the screenshot is the baked image, and both the ground reflections and the front side of the cube are less bright compared to the rendered image, also the energy falloff seems to be much stronger in the baked image compared to viewport

The color management settings has default values

Comment: The image on the right side seems to be suffering from denoising artifacts in the bottom left corner, could denoising be a factor in this issue? The image on the left appears to still be "noisy" - perhaps the denoise filter is causing the variance in the falloff and/or brightness.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett unfortunately even with denoise disabled I can still see the color variation and the different energy falloff